# Code on capacitors

Tags: capacitor, components

I accidentally let the magic smoke out of two (tantalum?) capacitors, one on an Arduino-based board and one on an RF reciever. Apparently they don't like being hooked up backwards. :-)

For the Arduino:
[image: Picture before burning it up]

The picture is before burning it up.
The code on it says `106C 13LE3`.

From [this site](http://www.electronics2000.co.uk/calc/capacitor-code-calculator.php) I was reminded that `106C` means `10uF +/- .25 pF`.

**What does `13LE3` mean?**

---

For the RF receiver:
[image: Ouchie]

The code on it says `226C 93J01`.

The same site reminds me `2206C` means `22uF +/- .25 pF`.

**What does `93J01` mean?**

I know this is two questions, but the root of my question is how can I find out what the second set of numbers mean so I can get the right parts to match.

Comment: I am not really familiar with the specific coding, but `.25 pF` is more likely to mean `25%` when talking μF.

Comment: Yeah, tantalum caps can become, um, "energetic!"  Before you replace these, look around the boards and see if there was any other damage done. Burned/discolored traces, etc.  Once I had a tantalum cap blow up, and a molten piece of _something_ (maybe tantalum?) landed on a neighboring IC and burned a holed into the top of the plastic!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: -

[image]

C, most importantly is the voltage rating of 16V and you don't really need to understand the rest of the codes cause they probably relate to the batch. [Here's](http://www.avx.com/tantalum/data/TPS/TPST106_016R1000s_LA.pdf) the document.